# Combination Question elegible to be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In my recent forays into the front page, I noticed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956222/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-string-array-with-ordered-elements) which has obviously been answered in it's separate parts elsewhere on the website.

Essentially the OP is asking [How do I convert an ArrayList to a String array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/convert-arraylist-containing-strings-to-an-array-of-strings-in-java) and [How do I sort an ArrayList of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18441846/2357233) in the one question. This seems to me that it should be marked as a duplicate because both of his questions have been asked before as separate parts. I understand it's not an uncommon problem, but it feels wrong to be answering this rather than just directing him to both previous answers.

But then again, due to FGITW it is gaining answers quite quickly.

So my question is does this kind of combo question add value to the site?

Comment: On Meta.SE: [How to flag a double question that is a duplicate of two others?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182349)

Comment: Oh the sweet irony

Comment: Eh, well over 50% of Meta questions touching on the topic of duplicates are themselves duplicates at this point. It's expected.